# Ember : toggleProperty is not working inside a jQuery Ajax GET

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I'm making an app that if the person is authorized the control panel will show up, and It's almost done but i have a problem with changing the property. 
Function this.toggleProperty is working great, but not in an Ember jQuery Ajax Function. 
What can I do in that case?

```
showControls:false,
         someName: function () 
    { 
          {
          Ember.$.ajax
               ({
                   type:"GET",
                   url:"http://localhost:3000/check/",
                   dataType: 'text',
                   success:function(data)
                   {
                     if(data==="true")
                     {
                        this.toggleProperty('showControls');
                     }
                   }
               });
           }
     }.on('init'),
```

And this is my example back-end in node:

```
    router.get('/check', function(req, res) 
{
        return res.json(true);
});
```

And this is my problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleProperty is not a function

Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

The `this` inside your `success` callback is another `this` then outside the callback.

You have two options:

#### Arrow functions

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Probably the best option. Arrow functions have lexical bound `this`, so this will work:

```
success:data => {
  if(data==="true") {
    this.toggleProperty('showControls');
  }
}
```

#### Save this away

You can simple just do something like `let self = this` before calling `.ajax()`, and then use `self` inside your callback instead of `this`. So `self.toggleProperty(...)`.

Comment: The both methods works great, Thank You very much for a great support, I need to learn the arrow functions, didn't used that before.